# Jquery: load тега 

Tags: jquery, теги, html

Проблема состоит в том что мне нужно загрузить тег <head> методом jquery .load(), но почему он не загружается.

Вот такой текст написан в документации:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Я английским не владею, но на сколько понял то наверное нельзя так делать.

Но мне то нужно заменить тег <head> и например <title> в нем.

Как сделать это?

И как загруженные элементы через .load() добавить в DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Страница-загрузчик:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
              dataFilter: function (response) {
                if(response) {
                    response = response.match(/<head>([\s\S]*?)<\/head>/)[1];
                }
                return response;
              },
              url: "page_2.html"
            }).done(function(data) {
              $('div#result').text(data);
            });
        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Страница-источник (page_2.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Second page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Результат:

```
<title>Second page title</title>
```

Только, если Вы выполняете такие странные манипуляции как загрузка head html-страницы через javascript, то, скорее всего, у разрабатываемого приложения проблемы с архитектурой.

Comment: @uzumaxy Может вы знаете как менять title и выбирать какие файлы js подключать? в том смысле как другим способом.
. А почему не load? и почему не добавляет элементы в DOM хотя выше строка 

      $(document).on('click', '.js_href_load_data a', function(){
      .. 
      }

Answer (score 0):

Title легко меняется:

```
document.title = "НовыйЗаголовокСтраницы";
```

Comment: Данный ответ не является ответом на вопрос. Вопрос относится к документу, загружаемому через `load()`