# Элементы не добавляются в DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

Задача состоит в том что бы добавить загруженные элементы в DOM, но почему-то это не получается.

Вот код:

```
  if(!!(window.history && history.pushState)==true){

  $(document).on('click', '.js_href_load_data a', function(){

  event.preventDefault();

  window.history.pushState(null, null, this.href);

  $(".js_html_load_data").load(this.href+" .js_html_load_data");

  });

  }
```

Comment: Чего вы хотите добиться этой строкой? $(".js_html_load_data").load(this.href+" .js_html_load_data");

Comment: @Лисёнок заменить блок, загрузив его с другой страницы

Comment: Может переменная this.href хранит инвалидные данные?

Comment: @uzumaxy данные загружаются нормально но не добавляются в DOM

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в .js_html_load_data не появляются данные, которые возвращает метод .load()?

Comment: @Лисёнок они появляются и успешно заменяются, только вот загруженные данные не обрабатываться JQuery.

Comment: Если есть события привязанные к загруженным элементам, то используйте метод .on() . Или напишите как именно обрабатываете.

http://api.jquery.com/on/#on1

Comment: @Лисёнок выше написал как я примеряю метод .on(), что еще нужно?

Comment: Если этот путь к ссылкам правильный: ".js_href_load_data a", тогда можно попробуйте записать так:

 $(document).on('click', '.js_href_load_data a', function(event){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы [уже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/287559/) задавали подобный вопрос. Как Я понимаю, подход с регулярками Вам не понравился... Блин, почему никто не любит регулярные выражения?! Ладно, перейдем к сути вопроса. Через load грузить не получится, по крайней мере у меня не получилось. Видимо какие-то особенности реализации. Предлагаю напрямую вызвать AJAX и обрабатывать ответ как jQuery object.

Но Я о5-таки крайне **не рекомендую** использовать подобный подход при построении веб-страницы.

**page_1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
              // Фильтруем ответ сервера на Ajax запрос
              dataFilter: function (response) {
                if(response) {
                    // Формируем jQuery объект
                    response = $('<html/>').html(response);
                }
                return response;
              },
              url: "page_2.html"
            }).done(function(data) {
              $('div#result').html(
                // Работаем с data как с jQuery объектом
                // Выбираем любой селектор и вставляем его HTML код
                data.find('#div-to-load').html()
              );
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page_2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Second page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div-to-load">
        <p>
            <b>Список супер-героев:</b>
            <ul>
                <li>Онотолэ</li>
                <li>Чак Норрис</li>
                <li>Ктулху</li>
                <li>Упячка</li>
                <li>VladD</li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page_1.html после загрузки в браузере**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
              // Фильтруем ответ сервера на Ajax запрос
              dataFilter: function (response) {
                if(response) {
                    // Формируем jQuery объект
                    response = $('<html/>').html(response);
                }
                return response;
              },
              url: "page_2.html"
            }).done(function(data) {
              $('div#result').html(
                // Работаем с data как с jQuery объектом
                // Выбираем любой селектор и вставляем его HTML код
                data.find('#div-to-load').html()
              );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
  <body style="">
    <div id="result">
        <p>
            <b>Список супер-героев:</b>
            </p><ul>
                <li>Онотолэ</li>
                <li>Чак Норрис</li>
                <li>Ктулху</li>
                <li>Упячка</li>
                <li>VladD</li>
            </ul>
        <p></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Подобный но не такой, на самом деле я ту проблему исправил просто добавив div из данными title и внутри кодом js, теперь появилась проблема что бы вытащить сразу же новые данные title в этом же запросе.